# How to get custom view for Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have created a custom view for my Toolbar for fargments where I have added to two ImageButtons to the view and I have removed the those items from the menu resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/video_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/camcorder_pro_96px"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/photo_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/compact_camera_96px"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I have attached this view to Toolbar in my MainActivity

```
toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

[image: Screenshot of Toolbar]

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't view the drawables that I have added. Instead it is showing black tiny slabs

Comment: try to use ic_launcher icon in the imageview, if it is showing properly then you have issue with image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the image on the wrong attribute in the `Imagebutton` and I dont think that `android:icon` exist either.

You need to set the image to the `android:src` attribute to set the image to the view

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

`android:icon`

> It is displayed to users when a representation of the activity is
>   required on-screen.

In that you should use **android:src** instead of **android:icon** .

`android:src`

> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView or ImageButton.